# Sublime Text 3 "draw_centered" doesn't have any effect

Tags: sublimetext3

Hi I'm trying to add some left and right margin white-space in normal, windowed editing mode in Sublime Text 3, running on Ubuntu. (I still miss Notational Velocity).

I have set up my `../User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file as shown below but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/IDLE.tmTheme",
    "draw_centred": true,
    "font_face": "Calibri",
    "font_size": 9,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Markdown",
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

In a related issue, while I was trying to check if `drawCentered` key was actually set to true I tried `view.get_status("draw_centred")` but got `"` as the response in the console.

How do I set a left and right margin in sublime text in windowed mode, and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably `draw_centered` not `draw_centred` (UK).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
view.settings().get('draw_centered')
```

and to set it:

```
view.settings().set('draw_centered', False)
```

Source: Bottom of page: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html

Here is the keybinding to make this toggle-able for me (sublime 3, linux mint)

```
{
   "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"],
   "command": "toggle_setting",
   "args": {"setting": "draw_centered"}
},
```